# Two sample similarity analysis for non-independent daily time series data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, similarities, two-sample

What two sample or other relevant statistical tests can be performed in `R` between two samples which are independent of each other, but the observations within each sample may not be independent, thus violating IID assumption? The values within sample has pixel (say 100 pixels are present in the study area) values representing wildfire severity, thus the daily pixel values are correlated.

The dataset from each of the two samples contain daily time series data, and each day has multiple observations.

One sample/model is the predicted model and the other sample/model has the observed data. So, the idea is to see how good or how similar the predicted model is against the observed data.

Comment: Although *independence* has a clear definition, "may not be independent" comprises a huge array of vague possibilities.  What, then, can you tell us about how you intend to model this lack of independence?  That will be crucial factor in selecting a test.  Another crucial factor is what exactly you mean by "similar" in your null hypothesis.

Comment: @whuber, because the data has wild-fire severity values for each pixel in the area, and thus the values are correlated. By similarity, I mean whether both follow the same distribution or are they from the same population, just like in the case of non-parametric tests. Do you want me add this to my question? I am new to this website so any guidance will be appreciated. One model/sample is prediction and the other sample is observed.

Comment: It usually works best to explain your actual application, because often crucial details are overlooked in trying to formulate an abstract version of the question.  This often obviates any need on your part to use unfamiliar statistical language, too.

Comment: @whuber, I have made edits to make further sense, does it have more clarity now?